# To declare or not declare DataAccessException in DAO interface methods?

Tags: java, spring, exception, dao

I see some Spring/Hibernate code having different policies regarding declaring `DataAccessException` in DAO interface methods.

Some do explicitly declare it and some don't (or only from time to time):

```
public interface FlightDao {

    boolean decrementSeat(Long flightId, int quantity);

    List<Flight> findFlights(String fromAirportCode, String toAirportCode) throws DataAccessException;

    public List<Flight> getFlights();

    Flight getFlight(Long id);

    Flight getFlight(String flightNumber);

    void save(Flight flight);

}
```

What would be considered the best practice and why?

**Update**

From section 13.2.2 of the [spring tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html), it is important to annotate the implementing DAO pojo with @Repository to make sure the underlying ORM (or JDBC) exceptions are automatically translated into the DataAccessException (runtime) exception hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/dao/DataAccessException.html), this is a RuntimeException, so wether you declare it or not makes no difference in terms of programming. When the user implements the method he can choose to omit this exception from the method signature.

The only reason i can think of for putting it in the method signature is to mark it so the user will know this method might throw this exception and thus he can choose wether to catch it and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

If there is any kind of exception in finding Flights / getting Flights/ decrement seats , the application calling these 'service' methods should have the final say in how to handle these exceptions. FlightDAO as a service should simply catch and throw all exceptions. You may find it useful to create a new user defined Exception ...call it ServiceException or MyDAOException and make all the methods in FlightDAO throw this user-defined exception.

Comment: I am not so sure about this strategy, because by letting these runtime exception climb the stack, Spring will catch them at the transaction level (if there is any), which will trigger the rollback.

Comment: True. The spring container should rollback if it's an insert operation and there's an exception. But I still think throwing the exception to the caller is essential. If you are trying to say getFlights and there's a runtime exception,the application invoking this service would find it useful to know that the list if flights is empty since there was an exception  and not because there were no flights for that query.